# BottomNavigationBar without highlighted items Flutter

Tags: flutter, bottomnavigationview

I'm going to have about 7 states for my screen and want to navigate them in specific order using BottomNavigationBar with two items, of which first goes "back" and second one forth. Problem is, there's a default index for BottomNavigationBar, which is 0, and the first option is always higlighted. Is there a way to make it no highlighted, or maybe another widget that looks like BottomNavigationBar, that fits better with what I'm trying to do? I use BottomNavigationBar in my app already for other screen, and would like to maintain the similar look.

Answer (score 0):

`currentIndex` default value is 0, You can use Row widget for bottom navbar and SingleChildScrollView for scrolling effect.

```dart
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Expanded(child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex)),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedIndex = i;
                  });
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can also use it with Pageview.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 properties in BottomNavigationBar you could set to achieve what you want: selectedIconTheme (to set selected icon style), selectedFontSize (to set selected label font size) and selectedItemColor (to set selected label color).

There you will find an example on this link:

https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-zo406s1o506?lazy=false&split=50&entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/main.dart